# Flutter Local Notifications doesn't execute code with app terminated

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I have an app that schedules alarms, which trigger flutter local notifications. When pressing one of the buttons on these notifications, the database gets updated to reflect that you've turned off the alarm.

However, when the app is terminated/closed down, it seems as if no code gets executed and the database doesn't get updated.
**The notification does get triggered, it's when the user presses a button inside of it that no code gets executed.** [Looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOK9R.png)

I'd like to know if what I'm trying is even possible, because at this point I'm not sure.

- The notifications are created using the zonedSchedule from the flutter local notifications plugin.
- The app does not get opened when pressing one of the buttons in the notification.

The code is as follows:

```
class LocalNoticationsService {
  LocalNoticationsService(
    this._notificationsPlugin,
  );

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin;

  Future<void> init() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings(
      'img/path',// path to notification icon
    );

    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      defaultPresentAlert: true,
      defaultPresentSound: true,
      notificationCategories: [
        DarwinNotificationCategory(
          'category',
          options: {
            DarwinNotificationCategoryOption.allowAnnouncement,
          },
          actions: [
            DarwinNotificationAction.plain(
              'snoozeAction',
              'snooze',
            ),
            DarwinNotificationAction.plain(
              'confirmAction',
              'confirm',
              options: {
                DarwinNotificationActionOption.authenticationRequired,
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    await _notificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: _onSelectedNotification,
      onSelectNotificationAction: onSelectNotificationAction,
    );

    final notificationOnLaunchDetails = await _notificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    if (notificationOnLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false) {
      _onSelectedNotification(notificationOnLaunchDetails!.payload);
    }
  }

  void _onSelectedNotification(String? payload) {
    // Not relevant to this problem
  }

  Future<bool> _confirmAlarm(AlarmPayLoad alarmPayload) async {
    // Update database
  }
}

// Top level function
Future<void> onSelectNotificationAction(NotificationActionDetails details) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  final localNotificationsService = LocalNoticationsService(
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin()
  );
  await localNotificationsService.init();

  final alarmPayload = AlarmPayLoad.fromJson(details.payload);
  await localNotificationsService._confirmAlarm(alarmPayload)
}
```

Due to this all running in the background, I've been unable to find a way to log things. I've tried using the http package to send post request to a webhook with some data, but these do not seem to trigger when the app is terminated, but do work when in the app is in the foreground or in the background(not closed).

Any post or videos I've found online about flutter local notifications don't seem to cover this problem or are using firebase push notifications and the associated package for background handling.

I'd be very interested to hear any feedback on what might be going wrong or what might be the solution and how handling background notifications works. If you need additional information on the code, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the code in release mode, kill the application process, and then test sending a notification in the terminated state.